# NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR DOM error while using the Tweet jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using a completely unmodified version of the jQuery Tweet plugin -- I haven't even changed the username yet.  You can view the code at tweet.seaofclouds.com. In dreamweaver, the plugin works perfectly, yet in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, it does not.

Using the Safari developer console, I see "NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM Exception 7: An attempt was made to modify an object where modifications are not allowed. jquery.min.js:12"

Firebug returns "uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIDOMNSHTMLElement.innerHTML]" nsresult: "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)" location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js :: anonymous :: line 12" data: no]"

Can anyone offer up a solution or link where I could learn more about this error and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

This is typically because you're using `innerHTML` after having defined your page's `doctype` to be `xhtml`...

This is especially evident with mootools if you were to use their `obj.set({html: ""})` -- will throw the exact same error in Safari.